# Save powershell get-disk as variable and the use it in if function

Tags: powershell

I want to make script run only from a specific usb drive. I want to make variable $drive which has output of get-disk command, and the, if $drive contains my usb serial - make some function.

$drive=get-disk -SerialNumber "980D06056030" | ft SerialNumber

if ( "980D06056030" -eq $drive ) {Write-Host "Yes"}

This doesn`t work =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use SerialNumber property like this.

```
$drive = (get-disk -SerialNumber "980D06056030").SerialNumber
 if ( "980D06056030" -eq $drive ) {Write-Host "Yes"}
```

Comment: @Kirill second part should work with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use Where-Object to filter:

```
Get-Disk | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Serialnumber -Eq "980D06056030"}
```

Note: First use Get-Disk and confirm the Serial number is displayed on the screen in the properties of USB. Some USB devices does not show Serial number.
You could also use where-object to filter the USB devices like:

```
$USBSerialnum = "980D06056030"
Get-Disk | Where-Object -FilterScript {($_.Bustype -Eq "USB") -and ($_.Serialnumber -Eq $USBSerialnum) }
```

Comment: It works for output "get-disk" function, as well as mine. Problem in the second part, wher i try to get serial number from variable an make some function if if contains my serial

Comment: One more time: "Get-Disk" function works fine, thanks. The problem in the secont part of my script "if ( "980D06056030" -eq $drive ) {Write-Host "Yes"}. I`m not sure, could it work at all, but idea is next: I make variable $drive with Get-Disk function, and next, if output of get-disk function contains my usb serial number - start next funtion. "Write-host" in this example.